# GWT CRUD GUI Model

Tags: gwt, user-interface, web, model, crud

Good day. I'm still learning GWT so please help me. I'm working on a project - `Web Application with GWT` on the Client Side. This app has lots of `CRUD` operations so I'd like to make a `model` for this. `Can anyone suggest a prototype for my CRUD class?`

CRUD on this app goes something like this:

When I clicked the Details button in a module, a popup will be shown that allows the user to do CRUD operations. This popup do have the module title, info on the selected item, and the buttons - Edit, New, Delete.

I have already finished building the base GUI for this project but I'm just starting to work on each module. I choose to begin on those module with CRUD operations. So, please help me and give your ideas on this project. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little bit general.
You probably have to deal with two questions which can be handled separately:

1. Communication with the backend.
2. GUI for CRUD operations

### Communication with the backend:

It depends on which kind of backend you are using.

**Java-backend:**
For Java backends the recommended client-server communication protocol is [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html).

**Non-Java-backend:** In case you are using a non-java backend (python, PHP, etc) you have to use [RequestBuilder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSONphp.html) using JSON or XML (I would recommend JSON).

For mapping JSON/XML to DTO's and vice verca you can use different methods:

1. Third party tools like [piriti](http://code.google.com/p/piriti/) which are based on GWT generators
2. [Javascript Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) (JSO)
3. [GWT Autobean framework](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) (which is used by RequestFactory btw).

### GUI for CRUD operations

For mapping your DTOs to your UI and doing the CRUD operations you can do it either:

1. manually
2. with the [Editor](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html) framework

I would recommend to use the `Editor` framework as it reduces the amount of boilerplate code 
 to move an object from your object graph to the UI and back.
The Editor framework works well with `RequestFactory` (`RequestFactoryEditorDriver`), `Autobean` (`SimpleBeanEditorDriver`) and `Javascript Overlay Types`.